# "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'app'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm getting this error when trying to test my lambda-function

```
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'app'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Here's my python code since I'd imagine it's an issue with my code? I also have my lambda function handler on aws set to app.handler since this file's name is app.py. Really not sure if it's an issue with my lambda function handler or my code, or both

```
import requests
import os
import smtplib
from datetime import datetime

# https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api

# empire state building
lat = '40.75009231913161'
lon = '-73.98638285425646'
exclude = 'minutely,hourly,alerts'

url = (
    'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?' +
    'lat={lat}&lon={lon}&exclude={exclude}&appid={API_key}&units=imperial'
)


if os.path.isfile('.env'):
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    load_dotenv()


def __send_email(msg: str) -> None:
    gmail_user = os.getenv('EMAIL_USER')
    gmail_password = os.getenv('EMAIL_PASSWORD')

    # Create Email
    mail_from = gmail_user
    mail_to = gmail_user
    mail_subject = f'Weather Today {datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")}'
    mail_message = f'Subject: {mail_subject}\n\n{msg}'

    # Send Email
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    server.sendmail(mail_from, mail_to, mail_message)
    server.close()


def handler(event, context):
    response = requests.get(url.format(
        lat=lat,
        lon=lon,
        exclude=exclude,
        API_key=os.getenv('WEATHER_API_KEY')
    ))

    data = response.json()

    rain_conditions = ['rain', 'thunderstorm', 'drizzle']
    snow_conditions = ['snow']

    today_weather = data['daily'][0]['weather'][0]['main'].lower()

    if today_weather in rain_conditions:
        msg = 'Pack an umbrella!'
    elif today_weather in snow_conditions:
        msg = 'Pack your snow boots!'
    else:
        msg = 'Clear skies today!'

    __send_email(msg)

handler(None, None)
```

My ZIP is located in an S3 bucket in python/project.zip and the structure of my zip folder is python/app.py + requirements.txt

Comment: What is the directory structure of your zip file with the code?

Comment: @Marcin I just have an app.py and a requirements.txt in my python folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the structure of my zip folder is python/app.py + requirements.txt

It should be only `app.py`, not `python/app.py`. Also there is no need for `requirements.txt` as lambda is not going to use it and install any packages you have listed there.

Comment: Now I’m getting another error saying “unable to import module app: no module named requests” My current version of python is 3.10.2 and the highest version I can select on lambda is 3.9. Is this the issue? Should I just put my application in a docker container and go through ECR?

Comment: @MP32 Its a new issue, thus new question should be asked. Lambda supports docker containers, so you can run your function as a container on a lambda.

Comment: @MP32 I see you made new question, but not accepted my answer which solved your issue. Please accept the helpful answers as this increases chances of your questions to the answered.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to have your function in a folder! I have my function inside my src/ folder. You just need to specify it in template.yaml with the 'CodeUri' tag

Comment: When I installed the requirements.txt file, the "No module named 'app'" error went away.

Comment: @Nate Please make question specific to your issue with relevant details.

Comment: @Marcin This was in response to your answer. You said there is no need for requirements.txt, whereas in my case installing it while running locally resolved the error of OP's question.

Comment: Using the sam-cli locally, the requirements.txt file and running sam build were necessary to resolve the app or requests not found error.